How do I make Links (text browser) default to using Transmission-Cli for torrent files or magnets?
When I open a torrent link or magnet through Links it tells me I havent specified an associated app or software to handle them.
Ive been through the documentation for Links, I've found the part for adding associations and I think I understand the principle but I dont understand how I actually specify to use Transmission-CLI for these specific file/link types. Ie what content type it is and how to format that line with that instruction.
